# Force video to play in flash player

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

As you may be aware YouTube by default uses HTML5 video player , but i have some requirement in which flash player should be used by default to play the video is there any solution?

Comment: are you saying you require youtube should use flash player?

Comment: there are per browser solutions - any particular browser you want to infect with flash?

Comment: Solution needed for firefox.

Comment: [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-flash-player/) looks like a winner

Comment: Cool this might help me test and find issues but isn't there any programmatic solution via javascript , i simply can't go and install this add-on on each and every user's computer :P

Comment: why do you think you need to choose how a user views youtube videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `&nohtml5=1` to the video URL

Comment: In case anybody wondering how to force in embeds it is like this `<object width="425" height="350" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/{videocode}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/{videocode}" /></object>` which wasn't my requirement but just in case if someone wants.